# Lookup a specific type from a list in C++ using templates not including base classes

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++14, template-meta-programming

This may be impossible so alternative solutions to the problem will suffice as well

I have a list of activities that I want to keep track of

```
class Activity {
    public:
        virtual void DoSomething() = 0 ;
};

std::vector<Activity*> activities;
```

Let's say I have the following child classes

```
class GraphicsActivity : public Activity {
    public: 
        virtual void DoSomething() { }
        void HandleGraphics() { /* do some management */; }
};

class UpdateActivity : public Activity {
    public: 
        virtual void DoSomething() { ; }
};

class PhysicsActivity : public Activity {
     public:
         virtual void DoSomething() { ; }
 };
```

Now let's say we want to grab one of these activities from our list. A function would look like

```
template<typename T> T* GetActivity() {
    for(int i = 0; i < activities.size(); i++) {
        T* cast = dynamic_cast<T*>(activities[i]);
        if(cast != nullptr) {
            return cast;
        }
     }
     return nullptr;
 }
```

We could use it like so:

```
activities.push_back(new GraphicsActivity());
activities.push_back(new PhysicsActivity ());
activities.push_back(new UpdateActivity ());

GraphicsActivity* g = GetActivity<GraphicsActivity>();
```

Let's say we have another activity that needs to use polymorphism to use some of the base class's methods.

```
class 3DGraphicsActivity : public GraphicsActivity {
    public:
        void Handle3DGraphics() { 
            /* Utilize base class function */
            this->HandleGraphics(); 
            /* do some extra work */
        }
 };
```

Now we want to acquire the same activity as before and our list now looks like the following in the exact order:

```
activities.push_back(new GraphicsActivity3D());
activities.push_back(new GraphicsActivity());
activities.push_back(new PhysicsActivity ());
activities.push_back(new UpdateActivity ());
```

But we want the original type of `GraphicsActivity`, so we go to acquire it:

```
GraphicsActivity* g = GetActivity<GraphicsActivity>();
```

We'll actually get a pointer to the first entry in the list because it shares a base class of type `GraphicsActivity`.

Herein lies the problem: how can I write such a list whose items must share the same base class `Activity` while also be able to acquire the exact type from the list without falling into the `dynamic_cast` trap we just explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`typeid` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) can be used to check if a polymorphic object has a certain exact most-derived type.

```
#include <typeinfo>
// ...

template<typename T> T* GetActivity() {
    for(int i = 0; i < activities.size(); i++) {
        auto* act = activities[i];
        if (act != nullptr && typeid(*act) == typeid(T)) {
            return dynamic_cast<T*>(act);
        }
     }
     return nullptr;
 }
```

Use this pattern with caution, because it limits the ability to make a class which acts exactly like another class except for specific changes.  But it might be appropriate in your interface.

Comment: Looked up typeid and RIIT and it seems the consensus is as you said, not safe. What makes it not entirely safe exactly? And what do you mean by it limits the ability to make a class with changes?